# Change label text from Hours:Minutes:Seconds to Minutes:Seconds

Tags: c#, label

I need to know if is there any way to change my `label` Text to `Minutes:Seconds` instead of `Hous:Minutes:Seconds`.

So i have one var that is updating  my label each second example `lbltime.Text = time;` and im getting `00:00:00` because the function from where im getting my `time` is giving me `00:00:00` but i need to know if it's possible to force in my `label` show only `00:00`.

But i want my `timer` giving me `00:00:00` i just want to show in my `00:00` in my label is there any way? i have tried somethings like this:

```
lbltime.Text.("mm\\:ss") = time;
lbltime.Text = time.("mm\\:ss");
```

But that don't work but i think that is something like that i just don't know how.
I didn't post the code where im getting my `time` because i want to change it only in `label` or only in time i don't want to change my function.

Comment: @vish sorry where should i put that?

Comment: lbltime.Text = time.Remove(0, 3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your time is string:then you can use :

`lbltime.Text = time.Remove(0, 3);`

if its datetime,you can use :

```
lbltime.Text = mytime.ToString("mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks i will accept your answer, it's simple and works without change my code.

The other ones are working too but i will need to change the code in many places. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply format to `DateTime` not to a string. I guess your `time` is a string.

I suggest, modify the format where `time` value is calculated.

If you don't have control, you could play with string functions and remove first `3` chars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your timer is a `DateTime` object :

```
 DateTime time = new DateTime();
 time = DateTime.Now;
 lbltime.Text = time.ToString("mm:ss");
```

Check the [DateTime.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) to see what kinds of format strings you could use.